# How to convert a binary String to Original String

Tags: python-3.x

I have entered a string as:

`str_data = 'Hi'`

and then I converted the string to binary using format() as:

`binarystr = ''.join(format(ord(x),'b') for x in str_data)`

Now, I want to convert binary string back to my original string. Is it possible to do so in Python? If yes, then how to do that?

I know chr() gives character corresponding to the ascii value but how to use it with binary string?

Comment: The same steps, in reverse. Split your string of `"0"` and `"1"` characters into groups of 8. Parse those into integers (making sure to use base 2 in parsing, not base 10). Then convert those integers into characters.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I have a query that since, I have used only 'b' not  '8b' so, how can I be sure that a character is being represented by 8 bits or more?

Comment: Is your string restricted to a specific range? For example, there don't seem to be any collisions in the binaries when using just ``string.ascii_letters`` (tried up to 4-length combinations) but many when using ``string.printable`` (1111 out of 8889 patterns of 2-length combinations). It's impossible to reverse when there are collisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str_data='Hi'
binarystr = ''.join(format(ord(x),'b') for x in str_data)
String=''
for i in range(0,len(binarystr),7):
     String+=chr(int(binarystr[i:i+7],2))
print(String)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Your code is easy to understand and helped me in solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

2 approaches: assuming a fix length for your source string (7 binary entries) or allowing a flexible length

### fix length (standard alphabet)

Here we assume that all the binary mapped from a chr entry have always 7 entries (quite standard).

split_source = [''.join(x) for x in zip(*[iter(binarystr)]*7)]

str_data_back = ''.join([chr(int(y, 2)) for y in split_source])

### flexible length (more general, but maybe useless)

You need to add a separator when you create binarystr

E.g. binarystr = '-'.join(format(ord(x),'b') for x in str_data)

otherwise it is not possible to say what was from where.

By adding the -, you can reconstruct the str_data with:

str_data_back = ''.join([chr(int(x, 2)) for x in binarystr.split('-')])